Does $\frac{f(x+\alpha_n)-f(x+\beta_n)}{\alpha_n-\beta_n}\to f^\prime(x)$ for $\alpha_n,\beta_n\to 0$?
I am considering the following question:
Let $\alpha_n,\beta_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at a point $x_0$, does it holds that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right)}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}=f^{\prime}\left( x_0 \right) ?
$$
My attempts: Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right)}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}&=\frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0 \right)}{\alpha _n}\cdot \frac{\alpha _n}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}+\frac{f\left( x_0 \right) -f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right)}{\beta _n}\cdot \frac{\beta _n}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}
\\
&=\frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0 \right)}{\alpha _n}\cdot \frac{\alpha _n}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}-\frac{f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right) -f\left( x_0 \right)}{\beta _n}\cdot \frac{\beta _n}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}
\\
&=\lambda _n\left[ \frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0 \right)}{\alpha _n} \right] +\left( 1-\lambda _n \right) \left[ \frac{f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right) -f\left( x_0 \right)}{\beta _n} \right] ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\lambda _n=\frac{\alpha _n}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}$. If $\lambda_n\to\lambda$ as $n\to\infty$, then we have
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f\left( x_0+\alpha _n \right) -f\left( x_0+\beta _n \right)}{\alpha _n-\beta _n}=\lambda f^{\prime}\left( x_0 \right) +\left( 1-\lambda \right) f^{\prime}\left( x_0 \right) =f^{\prime}\left( x_0 \right) .
$$
However, It is not guranteed that $\lim \lambda_n$ exists. I assume there are some counterexamples when $\lim \lambda_n$ does not exist, but I can't find any.
Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Dose this answer your question? (slightly different, it assumes that $f$ is continuously differentiable)

You need some conditions on  $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$. What prevents $\alpha_n$ from being equal to $\beta_n$?

If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then the result follows. There exists a differentiable but non continuously differentiable function (see here), so the statement does not hold.

@BoweiTang The linked question assumes $f$ is continuously differentiable, and under that assumption the answer is yes. But the OP seems to be only assuming $f$ is differentiable (and then only at $x_0$), so there actually are counterexamples.

@ShoboDra I'm sorry but could you please elaborate why the statement does not hold for a non-continuously-differentiable function?

As mentioned by Bowei’s comment, the answer is yes if $f$ is assumed to be continuously differentiable. (Or, more precisely, it holds as long as $f$ is differentiable in an open interval containing $x_0$ and $f’$ is continuous at $x_0$ - you can check that the answer linked by Bowei works as long as those two assumptions hold.)
However, there are functions that are (everywhere) differentiable, but whose derivatives are not continuous. As linked by ShoboDra, here is a standard example:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &, x \neq 0\\
0 &, x = 0
\end{cases}$$
Then you can check that $f’$ exists everywhere, $f’(0)= 0 $, but $f’$ is not continuous at $x = 0$. In fact, this function also provides a counterexample to your statement. Indeed, if $x_0 = 0$, $\alpha_n = \frac{1}{(2n + \frac{1}{2})\pi}$, $\beta_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}$, then $\alpha_n, \beta_n \to 0$, and,
$$\begin{split}
\frac{f(x_0 + \alpha_n) - f(x_0 + \beta_n)}{\alpha_n - \beta_n} &= \frac{\frac{1}{(2n + \frac{1}{2})^2\pi^2}}{\frac{1}{(2n + \frac{1}{2})\pi} - \frac{1}{2n\pi}}\\
&= \frac{1}{(2n + \frac{1}{2})\pi(1 - \frac{2n + \frac{1}{2}}{2n})}\\
&= -\frac{1}{(2n + \frac{1}{2})\pi\frac{1}{4n}}\\
&= -\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8n})\pi}\\
&\to -\frac{2}{\pi}
\end{split}$$
as $n \to \infty$, which does not equal $f’(x_0) = 0$.
